# bind_param not working (on a non-object) mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have read about 15 posts on here so far regarding issues like this none of which have been able to help me.

I have the following code:

```
$stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT cc.name, cc.company, cc.email FROM (`case_contacts` cc) WHERE cc.case_id=? AND cc.end_date IS NULL");
if (is_object($stmt3)) {
    $stmt3 -> bind_param("i", $case_id);
} else {
    die('Connection issue');
}
$stmt3 -> execute();
$stmt3 -> bind_result($name, $company, $email);
while ($stmt3->fetch()) {
```

When I execute it advises "Connection issue".  However just before `$stmt3` I can var_dump `$mysqli` quite happily.

I have manually entered the query into both phpmyadmin and an online query checker and both confirm that it is valid.

I have checked the permissions of the user, they are all fine.  In fact I am in the process of re-writing queries from mysql to mysqli and wantedto use prepared statements.  So the database user is the same.  I have had no issues with other prepared statements more complex that this so I am really at a loss to what I am missing.

I have even overkilled the '`' quote wrap on the statement as I know I should on every query!

Any advice, debugging tips would be great.  I have had a look around and the ones I have found are not providing an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt::prepare ( string $query )` return `TRUE` or `FALSE` read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

You can use this example:

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'admin', 'test');

$case_id = 603;

$sentence =  $mysqli->stmt_init();
if($sentence->prepare("SELECT name, company, email FROM case_contacts WHERE case_id = ? AND end_date IS NULL")) {

    $sentence->bind_param("i", $case_id);
    $sentence->execute();
    $sentence->bind_result($name, $company, $email);

    while ($sentence->fetch()) {
        echo $name . ' - ' . $company . ' - ' . $email;
    }   
}
```

Comment: But my current statement in testing should return true but returns false - if I do this won't it always be false.

Comment: @n00bstacker when you replace the ? by a value and test the query in phpmyadmin the sql is ok?

Comment: yup Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.0001 sec)

Comment: @n00bstacker edit the question with more code and add the sql of your table, to make a test in my server, let my know

Comment: That will be like 1000 lines of code - do you know of any ways I can debug prior to pasting all that code?

Comment: @n00bstacker I only need the code where you create the $mysqli object and the sql to create the database table "case_contacts" and 3 or 4 sql insert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74879/discussion-between-adrian-cid-almaguer-and-n00bstacker).